# Not able to access the value of hidden field in Jquery

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the value of hidden field on the click of list item. However the value is not getting set

Here is my PHP/HTML code:

```html
<div class = "input-group-btn">
    <input type=""hidden name="cpnoselected" value="asd">
    <button type = "button" class = " form-control btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"> CP No. <span class = "caret"></span> </button>
        <ul class = "dropdown-menu selectcpno" name="selectcpno">
            <?php
                    $link_address="#";
                    $class_active="active";
                    while($row=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_rows_cpdetailsfordd))
                    {   
                        if($result_rows_cpdetails[0]==$row['cp_no']){
                            echo "<li value='".$row['cp_no']. "'class='".$class_active."'><a href='".$link_address."'>" . $row['cp_no'] ."</a></li>";
                        }
                        else{
                            echo "<li value='".$row['cp_no']."'><a href='".$link_address."'>" . $row['cp_no'] ."</a></li>";
                        }
                    }
            ?> 
            <li class = "divider"></li>

            <?php
                $class_active="active";
                $link_address="#";
                if($result_rows_cpdetails[0]==""){
                    echo "<li value='".$row['cp_no']. "'class='".$class_active."'><a href = '".$link_address."'>Package Level</a></li>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<li value='".$row['cp_no']."' ><a href = '".$link_address."'>Package Level</a></li>";
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
   </div><!-- /btn-group -->
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript functionL

```
$('.selectcpno li').click(function(){
    //Get the value
    var value = $(this).attr("value");
    //Put the retrieved value into the hidden input
    $('input[name=cpnoselected]').val(value);
});
```

i am getting undefined index error on accessing the value through $_POST variable

Comment: You did wrap that code with `<form method="POST">...</form>` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Although the `<input hidden>` would work `<input type='' hidden>` makes very little sense. The most common way is `<input type='hidden'>`
2. `<li>` do not have `value` attribute, it is only applicable to form controls (ex. input, output, textarea, select, etc.). Use `data-*` attribute instead.
3. Accessing the value from `<input>` use `.val()` method.
4. Accessing the value from `<li data-*>` use `.data(*)` method.

```js
$('.selectcpno li').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).data("value");
  $('input[name=cpnoselected]').val(value);
  console.log($('input[name=cpnoselected]').val());
});
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="cpnoselected" value="asd">
<ul class="dropdown-menu selectcpno" name="selectcpno">
  <li data-value='A'>
    <a href='#/'>A</a>
  </li>
  <li data-value='B'>
    <a href='#/'>B</a>
  </li>
  <li data-value='C'>
    <a href='#/'>C</a>
  </li>
  <li data-value='D'>
    <a href='#/'>D</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. It solved my problem. But now when i am trying to access it in php using $_POST['cpnoselected'] it is giving me undefined index error. Please help.

Comment: You're welcome, @AvnishJain. Unfortunately I'm only frontend and that's a server-side question. You should make a new question referencing this question and tag it [php]

Answer (score 0):

change this `<input type=""hidden name="cpnoselected" value="asd">` to `<input type="hidden" name="cpnoselected" value="asd">` and then in your javascript

```
var hiddenValue = $(this).val();
```

as @tony said